# Exit the VM when an application stops running

Tags: erlang

I've got an Erlang application packed with Rebar that's meant to be run as a service. It clusters with other instances of itself.

One thing I've noticed is that if the application crashes on one node, the Erlang VM remains up even when the application reaches its supervisor's restart limit and vanishes forever. The result is that other nodes in the cluster don't notice anything until they try to talk to the application.

Is there a simple way to link the VM to the root supervisor, so that the application takes down the whole VM when it dies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When starting your application using application:start() you can add the optional Type parameter to be one of the atoms `permanent`, `transient` or `temporary`. I guess you are looking for `permanent`.

As mentioned in [application:start/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#start-2):

- If a permanent application terminates, all other applications and the entire Erlang node are also terminated.
- If a transient application terminates with Reason == normal, this is reported but no other applications are terminated. If a transient application terminates abnormally, all other applications and the entire Erlang node are also terminated.
- If a temporary application terminates, this is reported but no other applications are terminated.